# LINQ Expression Conversion / Concat from Int to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to Concat two expressions for the final expression

```
Expression<Func<T, string>>
```

So I have created expression  belwo code works fine for only string types , If I get memberExpression as Int32 or DateTime throwing exception

Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.String' of method 'System.String Concat(System.String, System.String)'

If I convert the expression as

```
var conversion = Expression.Convert(memberExpression, typeof (string));
```

getting  No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Int32' and 'System.String'.

Please help me to resolve

**Code**

```
MethodInfo bodyContactMethod = typeof (string).GetMethod("Concat",new[] {typeof (string), typeof (string)});

ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T));

body = Expression.Call(bodyContactMethod, cons, memberExpression);

return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(body, parameter);
```

Comment: Why not change your method signature to take an 'object' and just call .ToString() on everything.

Comment: Expression<Func<T, T2>>

Comment: Hi , I am using this expression in GroupBy , so I need it in above format

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of trying to cast to string, you could try casting to object then calling ToString(), as though you were doing:

```
var converted = member.ToString();
```

As an Expression, it will look something like this:

```
var convertedExpression = Expression.Call(
                     Expression.Convert(memberExpression, typeof(object)),
                     typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString"));
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be further simplified to:

```
var convertedExpression = Expression.Call(
                     memberExpression,
                     typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling `string.Concat(string, string)`, you could try calling `string.Concat(object, object)`:

```
MethodInfo bodyContactMethod = typeof (string).GetMethod("Concat", 
   new[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) });
```

Comment: well while I am  using this expression in LINQ Group By , giving concat not work with types object , object

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Richard Deeming's answer even though it's a little late.

```
Expression.Call(
    typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) }),
    Expression.Convert(cons, typeof(object)),
    Expression.Convert(memberExpression, typeof(object))
);
```

That should work just fine while allowing the signature to stay as you have it.