# Create an expression tree to convert a Guid or other type primitive type to a string

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

**When using Linq to Entities, the resulting query should run on sql server (not enumerating it into memory and then perform the conversion)**

I currently have a [project](http://ninjanye.github.io/SearchExtensions/) whereby I build expression trees for string searching.  I am currently exploring the possibility of **converting non string properties to strings** to enable searching on primitive types, such as `integer` and `Guid` etc.

I currently try to `Convert` a supplied lamda property to a string and then swap it into the expression tree using the following:

```
var stringProperty = Expression.Convert(property.Body, typeof (string));
```

> System.InvalidOperationException : No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Int32' and 'System.String'.

Am I trying to achieve the impossible or is there a way to **extend linq to entities** to support conversions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ Expression Conversion / Concat from Int to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862314/linq-expression-conversion-concat-from-int-to-string)

Comment: It is indeed similar but the solution they have is not compatible with linq to entities unfortunately

Comment: there's [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.stringconvert(v=vs.110).aspx) but it seems that it accepts only `Nullable<Decimal>`.

Comment: quick search showed that convert `Guid` to string is impossible with Linq to entities for now; regarding `integer` `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` should do the trick. Example of usage see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3292773/183267). It might be possible to convert to Expression version.

Answer (score 1):

The basic ideea is that Expression.Convert will be emitted in MSIL as a classical convert simmilar to this code (imagine that your property type is an int):

```
int value = 80;
string result = (string)value;
```

This operation obviouslly is not supported, so neither will be in your case. Alternatives:

I assume that you already have a variable, let's call that variable "property" of type MemberExpression (represents your property in an expression-like fashion).

1) Try to make a special static method convertor (an universal convertor):

```
public class UniversalConvertor {
     public static string Convert (object o) {
       return ... some convert logic ... :)
     }
} 

...

MethodInfo minfo = typeof (UniversalConvertor).GetMethod ("Convert", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

var stringProperty = Expression.Call (null, minfo, property);
```

2) Try to call the "Convert.ToString" API:

```
MethodInfo minfo = typeof(Convert).GetMethod("ToString", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { property.Type }, null);

var stringProperty = Expression.Call (null, minfo, property); // here we are calling the coresponding "Convert" method for the actually property type.
```

You could combine both methods: For property types that are known by the Convert.ToString API, you can use the second method. If not, you can make a fallback on the more generic method written by you. Feel free to implement as you like.